# What's the difference between <Directory /> and <Directory /var/www/> in apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, configuration

I was playing with the apache configuration files after a system restore when I noticed something I have never really though about too much. Here are the first lines of the default `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Since the root of a web server is usually `/var/www`, why is there the need to add a `<Directory />` in here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that you somewhere in your configuration define a `Directory` outside of `DocumentRoot` (e.g. I store my static pages under `DocumentRoot` but have web-applications in a separate directory outside `DocumentRoot`).  By having `<Directory />` in your configuration you define a reasonable default that's valid for *every* directory not specified by an own `<Directory>`-stanza.